# IOS app crashes after not opening for a while

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

Hello I tested this on two ios devices iphone5s and iphone6+

What happens is right when I open my app it shows the splash screen but then it crashes like .5 seconds after that.
So what I did is I make the application sleep for 25 seconds so I could have enough time to attach the PID to the Xcode debugger. When it attached the app seemed to load fine. I then stopped the process tried to start the app again from my iphone and it still crashes.

It's weird when it's connected to the debugger it won't crash when it's not it will only after a day of not opening it or so.
Does anyone have a clue of what might be happening.
All help is appreciated thank yoU!

Comment: A stack trace or log will be very helpful...

Comment: That's the problem there is nothing to debug because when I attach the process to xcode debugger it runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you enrolled in the Apple developer program? (99$ a year)

If not, on each build, the certificate installed with the app will be set to expire after 7 days thus suddenly the app run and crash.

Comment: Really! ok that's good news that means nothing is wrong internally with my app. Thank you!